# generation of unique random number using jquery

Tags: jquery

I m just creating the random number using below code

```
var number = Math.floor(Math.random()*90)+100;
```

But this gives me the two numbers has same numbers in between execution of this code.
Is there any way that i can generate unique random number where `no two numbers will be the same` .

Any ideas Please . Thank you .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use this, you specify a min/max and it generates a random between.

```
 var randomNumber = function(min,max){
        return Math.floor(Math.random()) + min
    }
```

Comment: if i give min, max range between 0-100 , no where two values will be the same . is it ?

Comment: Did you change the function again ? which one will work ?

Comment: I did. I use the initial one for generating a random array key, a whoopsie. I amended it to common JavaScript and removing the relevance to array keys (effectively just the `+1` bit)

Answer (score 0):

try two time random and give bit big gap like:

alert(Math.floor(Math.random()*Math.random()*1000));